# Ionic2 buildBrowserify fail on typescript error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I've started with ionic2 cutePuppyPics and did  a long way from there coding. at one point when I run gulp compile which include this :

```js
gulp.task('compile',function(done){
    buildBrowserify({watch: false}).on('end', done);
});
```

I get an error :

> [17:45:51] Using gulpfile C:\app\test1\gulpfile.js [17:45:51] Starting
>   'compile'... TypeScript error:
>   C:/app/test1/node_modules/@angular/core/esm/src/facade/lang.d.ts(102,21):
>   Error TS1005: '=' expect ed. TypeScript error:
>   C:/app/test1/node_modules/@angular/core/esm/src/facade/lang.d.ts(102,24):
>   Error TS1005: ';' expect ed. [17:45:52] Finished 'compile' after 1.11
>   s

I Check this file and the line is :

```js
export declare class NumberWrapper {
    static toFixed(n: number, fractionDigits: number): string;
    static equal(a: number, b: number): boolean;
    static parseIntAutoRadix(text: string): number;
    static parseInt(text: string, radix: number): number;
    static parseFloat(text: string): number;
    static readonly NaN: number;//this line error
    static isNumeric(value: any): boolean;
    static isNaN(value: any): boolean;
    static isInteger(value: any): boolean;
}
```

What could be the problem ? 
my dependencies in the packages.json file are:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ionic-native": "1.3.10",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "13.1.0",
    "browserify-istanbul": "2.0.0",
    "del": "2.2.1",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-shell": "0.5.2",
    "gulp-tslint": "6.0.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "2.13.6",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.9",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-gulp-tslint": "1.0.0",
    "isparta": "4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "karma": "1.1.2",
    "karma-browserify": "5.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.1.0",
    "remap-istanbul": "0.5.1",
    "require-dir": "0.3.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "ts-node": "1.2.2",
    "tsify": "1.0.3",
    "tslint-ionic-rules": "0.0.3",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "1.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I see that the error started when I used the isArray function and imported it with :
import {isArray} from "@angular/core/esm/src/facade/lang";

Comment: I think you can exclude `node_modules ` folder in compilation process using `tsconfig.json`, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: I did it

"filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "!node_modules/**"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/global",
    "typings/global.d.ts"
  ],